# How do I get my Javascript scripts working?

Tags: php, javascript

I am reading through the developer site for Wordpress and am just at the beginning of my learning of it. I have gotten my CSS to work via the wp_enqueue_style() but my javascript won't work via the wp_enqueue_script().

I have not added any Javascript on the pages themselves, I have the functions.php file with the wp_enqueue_script() in it which points to my /js/functions.js file where I want the toggleNav() function to work in for displaying the navigation menu differently on mobile.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

functions.php

```
<?php 

   function my_theme_scripts(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   'js/functions.js', array(), '1.1', true );
  };

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );

 ?>
```

functions.js

```
 function toggleNav() {
            var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
            if (!nav.style.display || nav.style.display === "none") {
                nav.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                nav.style.display = "none";
            }

        };
```

I've even tried placing a function call in the footer.php but it doesn't work.
When I add the javascript directly into the footer.php file it does work though.

Edit: Console output (I don't mind the images not being found as I'm just wondering about the js right now)[image]

Comment: did you check js file is enqueued properly or not ? can you see functions.js in view source ?

Comment: In the source there is the following in the head (but I think it might be from the wp_head(), not sure): <script type="text/javascript">
   window._wpemojiSettings =...
  </script> (I didn't add the whole script as it's too long for the comments)

Comment: functions.js doesn't show up in Network though

Comment: did you use child-theme ?

Comment: No I'm not using a child theme.

Comment: **wp_enqueue_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true );**   try with this.

Comment: Thanks but still didn't work.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting ? did you check console ?

Comment: I've added an image of what my console is outputting at the bottom of my original post so you can see.

Comment: there is nothing error related js. please try below code.

**wp_register_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false ); wp_enqueue_script( 'functions' );**

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: okay. **echo get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/js/functions.js'; die("you are in functions.php");** then see can you get proper url for js file ? or you can debug using define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to your wp-config file.

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: in **function my_theme_scripts(){ }** where you are enqueue js and css file. after check remove that line.

Comment: I got this: http://localhost/first-wp-site/wp-content/themes/cikada/js/functions.jsyou are in functions.php

Comment: hit this **http://localhost/first-wp-site/wp-content/themes/cikada/js/functions.js** url to new tab. can you see your js file code ?

Comment: Yes I can see the code

Comment: please check in your **header.php** have  **wp_head();** AND in **footer.php** have  **wp_footer();** ?

Comment: YES! That's it. I didn't have wp_footer(); in there. Thank you :) Why is it important? Strange the documentation didn't mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to include wp_head() in header.php and wp_footer(); in your footer.php

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<?php
  wp_head();
?>
<body>
```

footer.php

```
 <?php wp_footer();?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if you do not add wp_head() AND wp_footer() Wordpress hook does not fire using wp_enqueue_scripts hook .